# How to show instance names in CloudWatch graph labels?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a couple of machines in AWS EC2 and are running the Amazon CloudWatch Agent on them to collect metrics. Instead of the default `ImageId, InstanceId, InstanceType` triplet, the agent is configured to aggregate by `InstanceId` only:

```
    "aggregation_dimensions": [
        ["InstanceId", "path"],
        ["InstanceId"],
        []
    ],
```

In CloudWatch we can then use a `SEARCH` query to produce a graph:

```
SEARCH('{CWAgent,InstanceId} MetricName="mem_used_percent"', 'Average', 60)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Memory used graph]

It's great, except for the labels. These are only showing instance IDs, not instance names. But I swear that yesterday the instance names were showing up in parentheses after the instance ID!

I would really like to see our hand-picked, artisanal instance names here, instead of Amazon's industrial mass-produced instance IDs. I've read about [dynamic labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/graph-dynamic-labels.html) but they don't seem to be a solution.

Is there a way to make instance names show up reliably – either next to the instance ID or all by themselves?

Comment: I believe in you, I also saw the instance names between parentheses, but after refreshing the page they were gone, so I'm super confused now... Did you manage to workaround this?

Comment: Yes and no... CloudWatch turned out to be crazy expensive for custom metrics (such as memory usage collected by the CloudWatch agent), so we switched to Prometheus + Grafana. A bit more effort, but far more control, and in our case literally 100x cheaper.